# Bulbs for Round Kitchen Fixture Containing a Ballast

Tags: kitchens, light-fixture

I cannot seem to find bulbs for this fixture.  It is a 6 in. round recessed fixture intended for a single HID or fluorescent bulb, which was installed by the previous owner.

It contains a fluorescent bulb, but the bulb has no useful markings as to the manufacturer.

Attached is a photo of the label from within the fixture that contains additional details.

--Additional Info, based on comments--

Thanks for the quick response.  As I understand it A19, PAR38, and BR40 refer to the size and shape of the bulb--not the type and size of the base.  For example, an A19 or an A21 bulb usually have an E26 base (i.e., the part that goes into the socket).  The socket of this fixture accepts an E26 base.

I interpreted the label to mean that only HID and Fluorescent bulbs should be used with this fixture, and using a CFL or incandescent bulb would not be OK.  The existing fluorescent bulb is a 3 in round globe with an E26 base; it is labelled as a self-ballasted bulb.

Any suggestions for a replacement bulb are appreciated.

[image: label]

Comment: We need to see the bulb and the socket.

Comment: @AlaskaMan IIUC, `A21`, `BR40` and `PAR38` are all socket types, are they not? Any `1102/3RS- CDN Type NON-IC` bulb of the specified wattage and base type should work, no? A search for `light bulb 150w a21 base` turned up pages of results...

Comment: @FreeMan Thank You. Perhaps i should have said "I" need to see the bulb and socket as i do not have that knowledge in my database.

Comment: I just read the sticker in the picture provided and took a stab at it, @AlaskaMan. :)

Comment: If it "contains a fluorescent bulb" then it needs to have the same fluorescent bulb installed. The label is generic to apply to the fixture with watt limitations specific to incandescent bulbs; as you can see in your own photo, it does not specify bulb type or limitations for fluorescent or HID but refers user to a user installation manual. As @Alaska Man says, we can likely help you if you would just **post a picture of the old bulb and/or bulb socket**. Note: the ballast label may indicate bulb types but usually lists several, so not specific to *your* fixture.

Comment: @Freeman, the OP says the fixture has a ballast. All those bulb types on that label are for incandescent type bulbs, which don't use a ballast...

Comment: Fair point, @JimmyFix-it. My searches turned up incandescent and LED. Don't specifically remember any CFL in the lists, but there might be.

Comment: Those are for the fixture rating both ic and non IC . The lamp itself and the connections will be needed or pulling down the fixture and getting the wattage off the ballast will be needed. I don’t remember vary many different wattages in the fluorescent 6” rings , the ballast may be bad and a good time to upgrade to led before purchasing a new bulb for a bad ballast then find out with the low bulb and ballast you could have purchased a led conversion.

Comment: I think you are misinterpreting the label regarding fluorescent or HID.  Unfortuately you only showed us the label, and didn’t include a picture of the bulb socket or bulb that was found in it.  Did you not show the socket because it was the standard socket?

Comment: Thank you for the comments, they helped clarify the situation.  The bulb socket is the standard E26 socket and the bulb is a self-ballasted lamp.  I incorrectly interpreted the latter to mean that a ballast was part of the fixture.  However, in looking closer I've read that self-ballasted = CFL.  Therefore, a range of products should work in the fixture.

Comment: @FreeMan just fyi, the A,BR,PAR is the bulb shape, the number is diameter in eighths of an inch.

Comment: CFL, compact fluorescent lamp can be either self ballasted or remote ballasted, like a PL13 lamp.

Comment: Are there any labels on the attic/in-ceiling side of the can?

Comment: @NoSparksPlease thanks, I didn't know that!

Answer (score 1):

The lightolier 1105 reflector fits multiple housings, if you have a ballasted fixture like a 1101F18U, 1100AICMFT, or more recently an 1101LED you need to check the label on the rough in portion of the fixture to find what lamps are compatible with the ballast/driver.

You should be able to pull the reflector down out of the ceiling and see the junction box that is part of the fixture. If the fixture has a ballast it will be mounted to a cover of that j-box. Here is a [picture](https://www.lightoliertracklighting.com/product/lightolier-5-non-ic-frame-in-kits-compact-fluorescent-1001fr18u/) of a similar fixture with a white ballast attached.

Having found a self ballasted lamp in the fixture I would guess the housing is non-ballasted such as one of the models listed on the label you shown. The shapes and sizes of lamps shown are the types of lamps that they have tested in the fixture that won't damage the fixture and will operate the over temperature sensor if it has one. I'm sure due to the sheer number and styles of retail self ballasted lamps that the globe you have was never tested in that fixture.